# Does $last mean that ng-repeat elements are already rendered?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

### The Problem

```
if(scope.$last)
{
   //get container height
}
```

I've been thinking that it's the proper way of getting height of container which has ng-repeated elements inside. I've reached the conclusion that it's not the proper approach.

Have a look at my directive:

```
AdminApp.directive("ngExpander", function($rootScope, $timeout){

var GetProperContainerHeight = function(container, content){

    var container = $(container);
    var content = $(content);

    container.height(content.outerHeight());

    return container.height();
}

return{
    restrict:'A',
    link:function(scope, elem, attr){

        if(scope.$last){

            $timeout(function(){

                $rootScope.ContainerHeight = GetProperContainerHeight(attr.container, attr.content);

            }, 500);

        }

    }
}

});
```

If I hadn't added **$timeout**, the directive wouldn't have worked properly, because it wouldn't have returned proper container height (some negative value I achieved then).

### The Background

Directive works here:

```
<div class="SwitchContent" data-ng-show="ShowContent" id="testId">

    <div class="user-list-element"
                                data-ng-repeat="user in UserList | filter:userFilter track by $index"
                                data-ng-click="GetUserDetails(user);"
                                data-ng-expander
                                data-container="div.UserPanel"
                                data-content="div[id=testId]">

        <i class="fa fa-user fa-lg padding-r-10"></i> {{ user.name + ' ' + user.surname }}

    </div>

</div>
```

How can I achieve proper results without **$timeout**?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it without timeout, because Angular rendering happens asynchronously after your directive is compiled. But what you don't need is a number 500 which you probably don't like.

Just use the `$timeout` without second parameter.

```
$timeout(function(){
  $rootScope.ContainerHeight = SetProperContainerHeight(attr.container, attr.content);
});
```

This puts the task in the browser queue without any delay. You will still have some small time between the moment when browser stopped rendering and your timeout start but this is the closest you can do.

**EDIT**

Probably the problem is in your `scope.$last` method. What you can do instead of `if(scope.$last){` is watching the HTML content:

```
link:function(scope, elem, attr){

    scope.$watch(function() {
        return elem.html();
    }, function() {
        $timeout(function(){

            $rootScope.ContainerHeight = GetProperContainerHeight(attr.container, attr.content);

        });
    });

}
```

Although it can look ugly it always works for me. Whenever HTML of the element is changed (and it will be as long as `ng-repeat` changes the element's inner content) the watcher event happens.

You still need a timeout here because HTML is changed but it is not rendered yet, so you need to put it to asynchronous browser queue with the timeout.

This also has another advantage: current height is always reflected in your rootScope property while your method will only do it once on the directive load.

Comment: Please try the second suggested method